# How to control AVAudioPlayer using earPods remote control?

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, remote-control, headphones

I'm using `AVAudioPlayer` to play music

I want to control playing from remote controls which are part of using headphones.

I've already this:

```
override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent?) {
        let rc = event!.subtype
        print(rc.rawValue)
        //rc.rawValue: 101 = pause, 100 = play
        switch rc {
        case .RemoteControlPlay:

            playButtonClicked("")

        case .RemoteControlPause:

            pauseButtonClicked("")

        default:break
        }

    }
```

It's working great from this menu

But clicks on headphones are ignored. How can I fix it?

Comment: What version of iOS do you use? Have you tried the same solution on previous iOS versions?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the headphones send the `TogglePlayPauseCommand` event:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPRemoteCommandCenter_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPRemoteCommandCenter/togglePlayPauseCommand

Because I see you're using Xamarin, `RemoteControlTogglePlayPause` should be of interest

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIEventSubtype/

Comment: I don't think he's using Xamarin.  That's Swift code, and anyway the question is tagged [tag:swift]